# Armature hidden

Tags: armature

in the past I made armature for a character and after doing something else, the armature disappeared and now I am left with this blue "armature" and bones under Vertex Groups but I can't see Pose tab for my object.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you accidentaly delete (or Unlink) your armature. What you see in outliner is Armature Modifier with vertex groups of your object. Nothing more. There is not a way to hide something completely. Or you can attach a blend  via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com (to let as see if you didn't something else (like duplicated a Scene and delete it there or what ever).

Comment: Edit: When you open a blend and you switch in Outliner > Blender File list (or Orhpan data list - broken heart icon), and you go to Armature section do you see your Armature listed? Or you can try File > Recover > Auto Save if it is not saved in that version.

Comment: Upload blend, but chance is very low. did you checked auto saved files directory?

Comment: Try it again (it happened to me sometimes too) or use any other option to share. This Q is not going to have an answer anyway.

Comment: google drive, dropbox, wetransfer ... or any other servis you use to share files? btw take important from comments to extend or edit your question and i  would suggest to delete our comments here. thank you